# Saving font file for offline viewing

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I have a very client driven website and I want to be able to save the website for offline viewing.

In my website I have font-awesome version 4.3.0 included. When saving the page for offline viewing using Chrome, all the resources seemingly download as expected. When viewing the website offline however, the font icons are not shown.

Looking at the debugging console, it seems as if it did not include the actual font files themselves when saving the website for offline viewing. The font files are inside the font-awesome CSS file, linked using URL('...').

So my question is this:

Is there a way to include the font files in the web page such that when it is saved for offline viewing, the font files are also downloaded?

Comment: you need to save fonts whose urls are given in CSS file like : fontawesome-webfont.eot, fontawesome-webfont.woff, fontawesome-webfont.ttf, fontawesome-webfont.svg, and update the css accordingly

Comment: @DipaliVasani, I have done this and the fonts reside on my webserver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this on the command line tool `wget`. Download [wget here](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions?action=show&redirect=Faq#download)

and enter this in command line:

```
wget -p -k http://www.example.com
```

it will download all `CSS`, `JS` and `Webfonts`.

This will pass wget off as being a Mozilla web browser

Downloading Entire Sites:
Wget is also able to download an entire website. But because this can put a heavy load upon the server, wget will obey the [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file.

```
wget -r -p http://www.example.com
```

The -p parameter tells wget to include all files, including images. This will mean that all of the HTML files will look how they should do.

So what if you don't want wget to obey by the robots.txt file? You can simply add -e robots=off to the command like this:

```
wget -r -p -e robots=off http://www.example.com
```

As many sites will not let you download the entire site, they will check your browsers identity. To get around this, use `-U mozilla`.

```
wget -r -p -e robots=off -U mozilla http://www.example.com
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the most relevant answer so far. I guess the issue with this solution is I want to make it user friendly, so that someone who wants to use the site offline doesn't have to jump through hoops in order to download it for offline viewing. I could just provide the source as a download link if worst came to worst.

Comment: Just to add to that, I guess there may not be a way to include the font within the html such that chrome (or other browsers) will grab the file explicitly when using File>Save?

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called "fonts" in your main directory and store all your fonts in that folder.

For example if ColaborateThinRegular is one of the fonts in your "fonts" folder, you can call it with the following code in your CSS file.

Example

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ColaborateRegular';
src: url('../fonts/colabthi-webfont.eot');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

when it is saved for offline viewing, the font files are also downloaded

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what you have suggested is effectively what is done inside the font-awesome CSS file that is included in the html head section, and I do have the fonts stored in a folder in this manner on my webserver. The issue is that when going File>Save in Chrome, the font file does not get downloaded (havent tested it with other browsers yet).